# Как правильно расставить запятые?

Tags: синтаксис

1) Ты, что, в самом деле не придёшь? 2) Ты что, в самом деле не придёшь? 3) Ты в самом деле не придёшь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать два выражения: 2) Ты что, в самом деле не придёшь? 3) Ты в самом деле не придёшь?
Во втором предложении используется вопросительно-восклицательное слово ЧТО, выражение ТЫ ЧТО обособляется. Наречное выражение В САМОМ ДЕЛЕ играет роль обстоятельства и не обособляется.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1. ВВОДНОЕ СЛОВО ИЛИ ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВО

А) В САМОМ ДЕЛЕ  (вводное слово)

1)подтверждение ожидаемой действительности (в начале предложения):  В самом деле, туман уже рассеялся.
 2) исходный довод:  В самом деле, стоит ли тебе напрасно мучиться?
 3) авторское чувство (возмущение, недоумение): Что он, в самом деле, строит из себя умника?

Б) В САМОМ ДЕЛЕ  (обстоятельство, обозначает простое соответствие действительности):
 Коньяк в самом деле оказался хорошим. Он и в самом деле интересовался философией. 
Вы в самом деле здесь ни при чём?

1. ВОПРОСИТЕЛЬНО-ВОСКЛИЦАТЕЛЬНОЕ СЛОВО ИЛИ ВОПРОСИТЕЛЬНОЕ СЛОВО

А) Вопросительно-восклицательные слова образуются соединением слов ЧТО, КАК с местоимениями, частицами  и союзами.  Они произносятся с ударением и выделяются паузой в устной речи, на письме после них ставится запятая:  Что ж, я готов. Что же мне, хвалить его за это?

Б) Вопросительно-восклицательные слова следует отличать от сходных с ними вариантов, например:   Что же теперь будет?

Comment: В силу вздорности характера хотел начать спорить с Вами, но во время остановился: за Вами - знание, а за мною - предположения. Спасибо: Вы очень подробно всё объяснили!

Answer (score 3):

Однозначный ответ. Знаки следует расставить так.

Ты что, в самом деле не придешь?

В самом деле=действительно в данном контексте и вводным не является.

Comment: Спасибо. От исходного: "Ты что? В самом деле не придёшь?"